# How to fix Keyerror in GBTclassifier confusion matrix

Tags: python, pyspark, confusion-matrix, keyerror

while working with gbt classifier received an error in convolution matrix as keyerror...

```
cm_gbt_result = predictions_gbt.crosstab("prediction", "indexedLabel")
cm_gbt_result = cm_gbt_result.toPandas()
cm_gbt_result
#calculate accuracy, sensitivity, specificity and precision
TP = cm_gbt_result["1"][0]
FP = cm_gbt_result["0"][0]
TN = cm_gbt_result["0"][1]
FN = cm_gbt_result["1"][1]
Accuracy = (TP+TN)/(TP+FP+TN+FN)
Sensitivity = TP/(TP+FN)
Specificity = TN/(TN+FP)
Precision = TP/(TP+FP)

print ("Accuracy = %0.2f" %Accuracy )
print ("Sensitivity = %0.2f" %Sensitivity )
print ("Specificity = %0.2f" %Specificity )
print ("Precision = %0.2f" %Precision )
```

Trace of above mentioned code:

**Traceback**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: '1'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
2 frames
<ipython-input-56-24962cb86bab> in <module>()
      1 #calculate accuracy, sensitivity, specificity and precision
----> 2 TP = cm_gbt_result["1"][0]
      3 FP = cm_gbt_result["0"][0]
      4 TN = cm_gbt_result["0"][1]
      5 FN = cm_gbt_result["1"][1]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2904             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2905                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2906             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2907             if is_integer(indexer):
   2908                 indexer = [indexer]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: '1'
```

**cm_gbt_result**

```
 prediction_indexedLabel 0.0    1.0
0   0.0               479994    11598
```

can anyone suggest me why this error occured and how to resolve it...since i'm new to python ..if any silly errors please forgive me

Comment: @mck i've updated cm_gbt_result...in above code ...please check it

Comment: does cm_gbt_result[0]["1.0"] work?

Comment: no actually that line causing the error@mck

Comment: can you show `print(cm_gbt_result.columns)`?

Comment: @mck `Index(['prediction_indexedLabel', '0.0', '1.0'], dtype='object')` this is the result for `print(cm_gbt_result.columns)`

Comment: How about `cm_gbt_result.iloc[0].loc['1.0']`?

Comment: @mck `11639` was the output received for `cm_gbt_result.iloc[0].loc['1.0']`

Comment: @mck your idea was right...but got `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` ..... and i' working with pyspark... edit the answer if u can recorrect it

Comment: Oh it seems you can't get TN and FN then... your cm_gbt_result only got 2 elements, how can you expect to extract 4 things out of it...

Comment: now i got what's the error.... do you have suggestions to get desired result??@mck

Comment: it seems prediction is always 0. it's probably a problem of your model which always predicts 0.

Comment: @mck can you tell me y 0 accepted here not  1 class

Comment: it's probably a problem of your model which always predicts 0 and never predicts 1

Comment: thank you.... i'll try to find out myself